# call function from another function actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

I generate array of textfield, and array of random integers. Each textfield contain one of the random numbers from array. Next I have button to trigger function to search user-defined number in array. This function call a Timer instance to slow searching process. When I click a button function 
 is search and stop searching proces only one time. When I click search button again, flash give me this error :

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
at bakalarka_fla::MainTimeline/timerListener()
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

this is code

```html
input_hladaj.restrict ="0-9"
btn_hladaj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hladaj_fn);

var cislohladaj:int = new int;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,10);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
var t:int= 0;

function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void
{
 trace("Times Fired: " + e.currentTarget.currentCount);
  if(numberArray[t]==cislohladaj )
  {
   trace(t);
   TextFields[t].backgroundColor = 0x3AEE20;
   txt_vysledok.text = "Najdene na pozícii číslo " +t.toString();
   t=sizeOfArray;
   myTimer.stop();
   myTimer.reset();
   
  }
  else
  {
   txt_vysledok.text = "Nenajdene"
   TextFields[t].backgroundColor = 0xFF0000; //nenajde 
  }
 t++;
}



function hladaj_fn(ev:Event):void
{
  for (var g:int =0; g<sizeOfArray; g++)   
  {
   TextFields[g].backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF;
  }
  txt_vysledok.text = "";
  cislohladaj = parseInt(input_hladaj.text);
  myTimer.reset();
  myTimer.start();
  
}
```

Comment: Try to verify your `numberArray[t]` is not null because you forgot to verify `if(t < numberArray.length){}` and to reset `t` to 0 every time you want to do search.

Answer (score 0):

The timer is ticking 10 times. Length of an array may be less than 10. When `t` is more than array length, `numberArray[t]` returns null and error appears. You should add condition after `t++;`:

```
if (t >= sizeOfArray)
{
    myTimer.stop();
}
```